# On drag, force is applied to node before mouse click is released

Tags: d3.js

I've been implementing a force layout in d3js and I can zoom and drag the layout / nodes.

When I'm dragging a node, the behavior is fine, except that when I stopped moving, the node instantly starts moving back to it's original position, even though I haven't released the mouse click and so the event should still be considered in progress.

I tried to fix the behavior by setting d.fx and d.fy to current values, which doesn't solve anything.

Here's the code:

```
const WIDTH = 1600;
const HEIGHT = 900;

const V_MARGIN = 20;
const H_MARGIN = 50;

const ALPHA_DECAY = 0.03;
const VELOCITY_DECAY = 0.6;
const LINK_DISTANCE = Math.min(WIDTH, HEIGHT) / 10;
const CHARGE_FORCE = -Math.min(WIDTH, HEIGHT) / 3;
const ITERATIONS = 16;

const CIRCLE_WIDTH = 3;

const ON_HOVER_OPACITY = 0.1;

const c10 = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const SVG = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', WIDTH)
    .attr('height', HEIGHT)
;

const g = SVG.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'everything')
;

d3.json('got_social_graph.json')
    .then(data => {
      const nodes = data.nodes;
      const links = data.links;

      //Create force layout
      const force = d3.forceSimulation()
          .nodes(nodes)
          .alphaDecay(ALPHA_DECAY)
          .velocityDecay(VELOCITY_DECAY)
          .force('links', d3.forceLink(links).distance(LINK_DISTANCE))
          .force("collide",d3.forceCollide(d => d.influence > 15 ? d.influence : 15).iterations(ITERATIONS))
          .force('charge_force', d3.forceManyBody().strength(CHARGE_FORCE))
          .force('center_force', d3.forceCenter((WIDTH - H_MARGIN) / 2, (HEIGHT - V_MARGIN) / 2))
          .force("y", d3.forceY(0))
          .force("x", d3.forceX(0))
      ;

      //Create links
      const link = g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'link')
          .selectAll('line')
          .data(links)
          .enter()
          .append('line')
          .attr('stroke-width', d => d.weight / 10)
      ;

      //Create nodes elements
      const node = g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .selectAll('circle')
          .data(nodes)
          .enter()
          .append('g')
      ;

      //Append circles to nodes
      const circle = node.append('circle')
          .attr('r', d => d.influence > 10 ? d.influence : 10)
          .attr('stroke-width', CIRCLE_WIDTH)
          .attr('stroke', d => c10(d.zone * 10))
          .attr('fill', 'black')
      ;

      /*const label = node.append('text')
          .attr('x', 12)
          .attr('y', '0.25em')
          .attr('font-size', d => d.influence * 1.5 > 9 ? d.influence * 1.5 : 9)
          .text(d => d.character)
      ;*/

      //Refresh force layout data
      force.on('tick', () => {
        node.attr('cx', d => d.x = Math.max(H_MARGIN, Math.min(WIDTH - H_MARGIN, d.x - H_MARGIN)))
            .attr('cy', d => d.y = Math.max(V_MARGIN, Math.min(HEIGHT - V_MARGIN, d.y - V_MARGIN)))
            .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')');

        link.attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
            .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
            .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
            .attr('y2', d => d.target.y)
        ;
      });

      //Handle mouse events
      circle
          .on('click', (d, k, n) => {
            d3.select(n[k])
          })
          .on('mouseover', (d, k, n) => {


          })
          .on('mouseout', (d, k, n) => {
            circle
                .attr('opacity', 1)
          })
      ;

      //Handle translation events
      node.call(d3.drag()
          .on('start', (d, n, k) => {
            if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
          })
          .on('drag', (d, n, k) => {
            d3.select(n[k])
                .attr('cx', d.x = d3.event.x)
                .attr('cy', d.y = d3.event.y)
          })
          .on('end', (d, n, k) => {
            if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
          }))
      ;

      //Handle zoom events
      g.call(d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([0.8, 2.5])
          .on('start', () => {
            if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
          })
          .on('zoom', () => {
            if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
          })
      );
    });
```

I want the node to stay over my mouse cursor until the click is released. The node doesn't need to be sticky.

Comment: why do you set `cx`, `cy` and `transform` on nodes in the `tick`? If you want the node to follow the mouse you need to use `d.fx` and `d.fy` in the drag handler, do not set `cx` and `cy`, let tick do this for you

Comment: Yep, set fx and fy on drag - the tick constantly fires, the drag fires on movement, which is why the tick rearranges the nodes when the mouse stops moving. So set fx and fy on drag events and then set them to null on drag end.

Comment: Works. Thank you both.